# Can't open serial port - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port

I am trying to convert my WPF app to UWP app. My app uses the Serial Port class to communicate with a device. After I switched to UWP the same code that opens the connection to the device, using the Serial Port class, stopped working.

```
public MotorControl(string portName, Settings settings)
{
    this.settings = settings;
    this.serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, 9600)
    {
        DtrEnable = true,
        RtsEnable = true
    };
    this.serialPort.ErrorReceived += Port_ErrorReceived;
    this.serialPort.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
}
public void Connect()
{
    this.serialPort.Open();
    Thread.Sleep(this.settings.delayBetweenConnectAntWifi);
    this.SetNetworkMode("wifi");
}
```

When I am trying to open the connection I am getting this error:

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80070000
  Message=The operation completed successfully
  Source=System.IO.Ports
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Parity parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout, Handshake handshake, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Boolean discardNull, Byte parityReplace)
```

I tried to use Serial Device

```
public MotorControl(string portName, Settings settings)
{
    this.settings = settings;
    this.portName = portName;
}

private async Task SetupSerialDevice()
{
    string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector(this.portName);
    var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs, null);
    if (myDevices.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    this.serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices.First().Id);
    this.serialDevice.BaudRate = 9600;
    this.serialDevice.DataBits = 8;
    this.serialDevice.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
    this.serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
    this.serialDevice.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;
    this.serialDevice.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
    this.serialDevice.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
    this.dataWriter= new DataWriter(this.serialDevice.OutputStream);
    this.dataReader= new DataReader(this.serialDevice.InputStream);
    this.readPortThread = new Thread(this.ReadPort);
    this.readPortThread.Start();
}
public async void Connect()
{
    await this.SetupSerialDevice();
    Thread.Sleep(this.settings.delayBetweenConnectAntWifi);
     this.SetNetworkMode("wifi");
}
```

But, SerialDevice.FromIdAsync keeps returning null.

```
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:genTemplate="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/developer/windowsTemplateStudio"
  xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp genTemplate iot rescap">
.
.
.
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose"/>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <iot:Capability Name="lowLevelDevices"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="serialCommunication">
      <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

Comment: It seems that WPF and UWP have different thinking and API. See these articles. [Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication), [Windows-universal-samples/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess/cs/](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess/cs), [Serial Class Per Universal Windows Platform - Part One](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/serial-class-per-universal-windows-platform-part-one/), [UWPアプリでArduinoとシリアル通信](http://shirotsuku.sakura.ne.jp/blog/?p=1369)

Comment: I update my question with me resent changes

Comment: Have you set the `DeviceCapability` entry in the `Package.appxmanifest` file described in the article introduced?

Comment: yes, see edit above.
it able to find a device but the FromIdAsync returns null

Comment: If so, please download and build the sample program project introduced and check the operation. You may need to use DevicePath with VID/PID instead of "COMx" for the port name.

Comment: the function ```FromIdAsync``` return an object at the sample program but at my project, it doesn't. the function input looks the same.

Comment: For example, enumeration, selection and connection(Open) of devices are performed in [this source of example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess/cs/Scenario1_ConnectDisconnect.xaml.cs). Among them, the ConnectToDevice_Click() function is the part that opens the selected device. Do you want to check the operation one step at a time by debugging this? I tested the device Id("\\\\?\\usbcdcacm#VID_0C2E&PID_090A#1&2b53a856&0&15222B2308_00#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}") and the Name("Xenon 1900 Area-Imaging Scanner (COM3)").

Comment: I did it, I debugged till [this file](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess/cs/EventHandlerForDevice.cs#L220) to ```OpenDeviceAsync``` function.
I compared my device info to the one in the sample and they look identical, but the sample's returned value and mine returned null.

Comment: [Here is a Japanese Q&A article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/eb524a80-a951-4fd0-8b14-f44662ef9907/12487124961245212473124342035112358123921236512398fromidasync12398?forum=winstoreapp), in which there is a description that FindIdAsync was null due to the group policy. Such things may be related as well. Or if the sample program is working and communicating, how about re-programming in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that before I tried to connect to the device I used this function to find all ports:

```
public async static Task<ObservableCollection<string>> GetPortNames()
{
    string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
    var deviceCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
    ObservableCollection<string> portNamesList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    foreach (var item in deviceCollection)
    {
       SerialDevice serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(item.Id);
       string portName = serialDevice.PortName;
       portNamesList.Add(portName);
    }
    return portNamesList;
}
```

and i didn't do a `serialDevice.Dispose();` at the end of the `foreach`.

After adding `serialDevice.Dispose();` I was able to use the good old `SerialPort`.